Adding an IF statement to a Measure
I have an existing Measure to calculate Project Management Time:
Project Management Time Unit = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[Unit]),
    FILTER('Data', 'Data'[Product - Title] = "Project Management Time")
  )

The Data table also a column called "Action Code", Id like to create an IF statement that says:
Only calculate Project Management Time if the Action Code = "SK"
After some research, I think I may have to use a SWITCH function than an IF function but Im not sure. I cant seem to accurately build an accurate IF statement and have tried the following and Im seeing no data:
Project Management Time Unit 2 =
  IF(
    MAX('Data'[Action Code]) = "SK",
    CALCULATE(
      SUM('Data'[Unit]),
      FILTER('Data', 'Data'[Product - Title] = "Project Management Time")
    ),
    BLANK()
  )


No need for IF, instead you add the second condition to the FILTER.
Like:
Project Management Time Unit = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[Unit]),
    FILTER(
      'Data',
      'Data'[Product - Title] = "Project Management Time") &&
      'Data'[Action Code] = "SK"
    )
  )

You can also write it without the FILTER:
Project Management Time Unit = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[Unit]),
    'Data'[Product - Title] = "Project Management Time") &&
    'Data'[Action Code] = "SK"
  )

And you can also have the conditions comma separated vs having && (which only can be used on the columns from the same table as each other).
Project Management Time Unit = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[Unit]),
    'Data'[Product - Title] = "Project Management Time"),
    'Data'[Action Code] = "SK"
  )

